# how to extend the Datepicker's year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

the default dropdown year is form 2000 to 2020, how to extend it. thank you. now, i want to set it to 2000  to 2060. how should i do.

Comment: Don't you know the [world ends in 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_phenomenon#Apocalypse)? :P

Comment: i thought all programmers knew that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use yearRange or minDate/maxDate to set the range for the jQueryUI Datepicker. Look in the docs under the Options tab.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 1):

Year range of the drop-down defaults to c-10:c+10 - a 20yr range.  If you use min/maxDate your years will be substituted but the -10 & +10 from your default date will remain, forcing users to continually click the end of the range to get a new range set.

The solution is to use yearRange instead of min/maxDate. For instance, yearRange: "c-80:c+5" will give a range of 80 yrs prior to your default date and 5 yrs after that date, all in one continuous range of years in the drop-down. So, if the default date is -20Y, you can get ages from 100yrs old to 15 yrs old.  I hope this helps.